# Enums in Python: isInstance error

Tags: python, enums

What is wrong with this code and is that implementation correct?

```
from enum import Enum

class Test(object):
    Filters = Enum('Filters', 'A B C')  
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def aaa(self, filters):
        if(isinstance(filters, self.Filters.B)):
            print 'OK'
        else:
            print 'NOT OK'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().aaa(Test.Filters.B)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    Test().aaa(Test.Filters.B)
  File "test.py", line 9, in aaa
    if(isinstance(filters, Test.Filters.B)):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute it? if no, whats the error message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
self.Filters.B
```

is not defined. You defined

```
Filters.B
```

Also:

```
self.Filters.B
```

needs to be:

```
type(self.Filters.B)
```

it works like this:

```
class A():
    pass

isinstance(3, int) == True
isinstance(3,type(4)) == True
isinstance("hello", type('something')) == True
isinstance("hello", str) == true
isinstance(A(), type(A())) == True
isinstance(A(), A) == True
```

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem.

Comment: i don't get it. How to fix it, or even better. How should that be made correctly?

Comment: Note that using `if isinstance(filters,  type(self.Filters.B))` (or whatever exactly you did, it's not really clear from the answer) will only check whether `filters` is a `Filter`, not whether it's `Filter.B`. Try passing `Fitler.A` as parameter.

Comment: `isinstance(A(), type(A)) == True` wrong! `type(A)` is `type`. You can do either `isinstance(A(), A)` or `type(A()) == A`, but `isinstance(A(), type(A))` won't work.

Comment: THANKS guys for all the help and details! You are awesome! I've finally got that!

Comment: @MeLikeCookies If this helped you, that's fine, but I seriously doubt that this will work. (Although it's hard to tell what exactly this answer is suggesting to do in the first place) If you check for `type(self.Filters.B)`, you will only see whether you have an enum value, but not _which_ enum value, whether it's `Filters.A` or `Filters.B`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know if the `filters` parameter is a member of the `Test.Filters` Enum, you have three choices

- `isinstance(filters, Test.Filters)`
- `filters in self.Filters`

(`Test` and `self` are interchangeable.)

If you want to know if the `filters` parameter is `Test.Filters.B` then a simple comparison will work:

```
filters is self.Filters.B
```

Comment: Used this for IronPython: `filters in self.Filter`

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is quite clear:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

`Filters.B` is not a class or type. Instead of using `isinstance`, just compare the value that you got with the one you want:

```
if filters is Test.Filters.B:
```

Also, `Filters` is an attribute of the class, not of the instance, so you should probably rather use `Test.Filters`, although `self.Filters` seems to work, too.